# UITableviewCell with auto layout causes animation on init on iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, ios8, autolayout

I've got a head scratcher here.

Tableview in iOS 8.

Cells are laid out with auto layout in a .xib file.

When cells are inited (when there aren't enough to dequeue) it causes an animation as it resizes them for iPhone 6Plus.

Specifically the right side has a UIView that slides from left to right.

What I think is going on:

I think the xib is a 320 width and when it's autolaidout for this tableview on a wider screen it's not doing it before it appears on the screen and then the setNeedsDisplay is being animated. If I set the width in the xib to 500 it moves left like it's shrinking. Obvi it doesn't make sense to have a xib for every screen size.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried setNeedsLayout and layoutIfNeeded?

Comment: Does it also do this for the iPhone 6 simulator?

Comment: I'm not actually calling setNeedsDisplay. I'm letting the tableview do everything. They are pretty simple cells.

Comment: This was totally my fault. Had to do with the async loaded images in the cell.